# How to use the promo roles in the resistance?

Tags: the-resistance

I got the Coup kickstarter edition, which included some promos for The Resistance - Merlin, Assassin and the Inquisitor tile.  But there are no rules for them.  I know they reimplement parts of Avalon, but I can't find the rules online for that.  How do they work?

Comment: Is the a Resistance or a Coup question?

Comment: Resistance.  I believe the cards are now also in one of the resistance expansions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rules found on the Coup kickstarter page which included these promos:
http://www.kickstarter.com/projects/2012515236/coup-bluff-and-deception-in-the-world-of-the-resis/posts/694256